# Django - redirect another client to a specific page

Tags: django, redirect

This may be weird. Here is the scenario:

I have a view. And there are 2 clients connected to my django app. what i want is, when `client1` sends a request to my `view`; i want to redirect `client2` to another `url`. for example (pseudo-like) :

```
def some_view(request, other_clients_username):
    try:
        client2 = UserProfile.objects.get(username=other_clients_username)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('user not found')

    client2.redirect('/door-screen/')
    return HttpResponse('%s redirected successfully', %client2.username)
```

`client1` sends a request to `some_view` with a `username` parameter.

**If `user` exists, the client which is logged in by `user` should be redirected to `door-screen` page.**

Before this i never needed something like this. I even cant imagine how to do this. `Redirecting a user which is not request's owner`.

Any kind of help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: `client1` and `client2` accessing same view doesn't mean both are stored there . both request will be considered as separate and none knew about which client is currently accessing that view . As I understand , you want functionality that at any time only one user is accessing your particular view . is it ?

Comment: @PriyankPatel yes. `client1` and `client2` doesn't have to access to same view at same moment. one of them accesses that view, and redirects other one to some url.

Comment: you need some transaction lock type functionality . I would create one db table (with only one entry) and store current user who is accessing that view in that table . But I believe it will have a negative impact on performance .

Comment: what do you want your client2 to be like? I mean who is the target? how do you want to specificaly refer to this client2? Is it a client with a certain username or email? Is it a client that has the oldest login session? or is it a group of clients? or all the clients?

Comment: @MihaiZamfir all clients are registered and logged in users with an active session. and yes, i can find them by username or their `PK`.

Comment: ok, so you want to redirect all the other users that are logged in, right?

Comment: not all of them. particular ones. one redirection on each request @MihaiZamfir

Comment: which particular one? you have to know which user you want to redirect. how do you target him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be to use websockets or a library like [Pusher](http://pusher.com). Basically you'd send a message out on the wire within pusher that would tell client2's browser to redirect to a given URL. Obviously this is fairly easy to get around if a user knows that's going to happen.

Anyway, your backend view would look something like this:

```
p = pusher.Pusher(app_id='your-pusher-app-id', key='your-pusher-key', secret='your-pusher-secret')
p[client2.pusher_channel].trigger('redirect', {'url': '/door-screen/'})
```

Note that this assumes you're using https://github.com/pusher/pusher_client_python

Your template would need to pass the pusher channel though so client2's browser connects to the right channel. You can do that by either storing the channel id in a hidden input, rendering it as a var in javascript on the template itself, or you could even have it be passed through an ajax call. Though I'd probably go with one of the first two just because it's significantly easier.